# Where can i add google-services.json in xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

Hi we are developing Xamarin application where we want monitor how many peoples install application from our referral id.

Im find this document https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ 
where it says "Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the app/ or mobile/ directory of your Android Studio project.".

I have visual studio (2013) project where these folders are missing of course. Question is, where i add the google-services.json file in visual studio project ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's now documentation at "Add the Google Services JSON File", https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/ .

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer correct. Please consider updating the accepted answer to @snotyak's answer below.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know when it became necessary, but as I'm posting this (in May 2017), it is necessary. I placed mine in the same directory that my Android `.csproj` file was located. I then added it to the project and made sure that `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.targets` was in my `.csproj`. I read that rebuilding would be sufficient for making the proper build action to appear, but building and restarting XS is what did it for me. The final result in my `.csproj` was this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It depends on the version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices you are using. For example in the 29.0.2 the task GoogleServicesJson don't exist. Only in newer versions.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to have multiple `GoogleServicesJson` `ItemGroup` by using `Condition` statements in `.csproj`?

Comment: It's a shame that people post an answer and not respond to any comments after.

Comment: What does that mean "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.targets was in my .csproj"? That is not a library, so what is the syntax exactly?

Comment: Totally nailed it Nov 2019

Comment: I tried adding the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base package, unload the project, add the line to the cproj, reload the project, and it didn't work. I had to shut down and restart Visual Studio. The usual madness....

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to your solution using file explorer and Copy the google-services.json inside Droid folder.
2. Open visual studio and go to solution explorer.
3. Right click on Droid project -> Add -> Existing Item and select google-services.json from file browse (it will added google-services.json to the solution).
4. Right click on the google-services.json and go to properties.
5. In the Properties pane, set the Build Action to GoogleServicesJson.

An example from MSFT Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android#3-google-servicesjson

Comment: GoogleServicesJson never appears in the Build Action. I've closed and re-opened the app, it's definitely in the Android app in Xamarin.Forms. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried this with Xamarin.Android in vs2017, it had worked fine for me following above steps.

Comment: @niico add Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base to your project via Nuget, and reload your project. Then it should show up

Answer (score 11):

In order to have the option of set Build Action to GoogleServicesJson you should install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base via  Nuget first. then close VS and reopen.