# Xamarin - Integrate firebase to Xamarin.android project

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERyvuOfM60g) to integrate firebase to my Xamarin project

I face issue in  step of adding google-services.json file to .csproj project

after adding this file and restart visual studio , project not responding and keep frizzing

after research I found answer saying **[file is necessary for Xamarin projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435552/where-can-i-add-google-services-json-in-xamarin-app)**

so I removed json file and replaced it with my code to initiate firebase

```
private void ConfigureFireBase()
        {
            var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetApplicationId(GetString(Resource.String.applicationId))
            .SetApiKey(GetString(Resource.String.applicationId))
            //.SetDatabaseUrl("Firebase-Database-Url")
            .SetGcmSenderId(GetString(Resource.String.applicationId))
            .Build();

            var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
                //Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId.Token, instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.applicationId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));
            });

            }
```

but till now cant receive token

Comment: Not entirely familiar with Xamarin, but why is `DeleteInstanceId()` being called after it's being initialized? Shouldn't you just be calling `GetToken()`?

Comment: Could you please follow the [official process](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/)?