# Making the FIrebasePushNotficaition plugin sample work

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I have been trying to make the FirebasePushNotification plugin work. But so far i haven't had much chance.
The notification is sent but nothing happen. I guess it's intercepted because i dont receive it (I tried sending notifs without the plugin it works well) but the code i put in the OnNotificationReceived event isn't triggered.
If some one can help me on this that would be great.

So I decided to download their sample and try to make it work. But I am facing a problem. I deleted their google-services.json. Then I went to the firebase console to create a new one. I added the file to the android project and I reopened the solution. But when I try to set the file property to GoogleServicesJson there isn't this option on the menu.

I tried to close and reopen the solution multiple times but no luck.

What could i try to force this property ?

I thank you for your time.

Comment: Try clean and rebuild. Then close and open VS

Comment: @Anand It didn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Do you test on android real device ?  Is `OnNotificationReceived` not triggered in foreground or backgound ?

Comment: @Cole Xia - MSFT : Yes i test on a real device. OnNotificationReceived isn't triggered on both.

Comment: One more question , what's the version are you using  ? Is it the latest ?

Comment: @Cole Xia - MSFT : if your are talking about the plugin, yes. I am also using android 9 for the project xamarin android. And android 8.0.0 for the phone which is a samsung galaxy s8.

Comment: How do you send the payload ? please check the tutorial : https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/FirebaseNotifications.md

Comment: @Cole Xia - MSFT : I send it throw the firebase console.

Comment: You can edit project file and add it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435552/where-can-i-add-google-services-json-in-xamarin-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can i add google-services.json in xamarin app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435552/where-can-i-add-google-services-json-in-xamarin-app)